# Shift cell value based on column conditions

Tags: pandas, shift

I will like to shift value based on column and A B C and inside "Type" Column.

This is my dataframe:

```
Name   Type   A   B   C
John   AR     W   S   W
John   BR   
John   CR
Jack   AR     S   S   A
Jack   BR   
Jack   CR
```

Desired dataframe before using melt function:

```
Name   Type   A   B   C
John   AR     W       
John   BR         S
John   CR             W
Jack   AR     S       
Jack   BR         S
Jack   CR             A
```

Comment: Can you put the data as text instead of pictures?

Comment: Does the content of  the "Type" column affect the amount of shift? Or is it just column A shifts 0, column B shifts 1 and Column C shifts 2?

Comment: is this: column A shifts 0, column B shifts 1 and Column C shifts 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the shift function on each column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['W','','','S','',''],'B':['S','','','S','',''],'C':['W','','','A','','']})

df.B = df.B.shift(1)

df.C = df.C.shift(2)
```

Comment: OP is trying to shift based on the contents of the column `Type`. If the value in column `Type` contains `B` then the value of column `B` should be moved to that row. If 'BR' is is 2nd row for 'Jack' & 3rd row for 'John', your code will not work (in the posted example both are at 2nd row, so it will work).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
def func(x):
    for col in x.columns[2:]:
        for index,val in x.iterrows():
            if val.Type[0]==col:
                x[col]=x[col].shift(index-x.index[0])
    return x
df.groupby('Name').apply(func).fillna(' ')
```

**Input**

```
    Name    Type    A   B   C
0   John    AR      W   S   W
1   John    BR          
2   John    CR          
3   Jack    AR      S   S   A
4   Jack    BR          
5   Jack    CR
```

**Output**

```
   Name     Type    A   B   C
0   John    AR      W       
1   John    BR          S   
2   John    CR              W
3   Jack    AR      S       
4   Jack    BR          S   
5   Jack    CR              A
```